# Sum of specific cells, up to a given amount

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am attempting to create an overflow spreadsheet using formulas.  The "Starting Petty Cash" (on the right) is the carryover from the previous term, and is manually entered.  The "Count", just above this, is simply a grand total.

My issue lies in cell B2 (showing the value $300.00 in the screenshot).  I want this cell to first take the number from "Starting Petty Cash", then add the values from B5:B14 until the sum reaches 300, then stop adding.

[image]

Comment: When you reference cells it really helps to show the row numbers and column letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use this cell in B2

`=min(F3+sum(B5:B14),300)`

Will sum the values you mentioned but be capped at 300.

Comment: That works. I was thinking an `if` but this is probably better.